# i have been trying to make it so that if user scrolls they will get scrolled to a specific position using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

The scroll into view and if statement to read user scroll is working individually but cant get them to work together

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(window).bind('mousewheel', function(event) {
         if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0) {
            console.log('Scroll up');
            window.scrollTo(0,0);
        }
        else{
        console.log('Scroll down');
        document.querySelector('#PROJECTS-2').scrollIntoView();
    }})
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Explanation:** When the mouse wheel is moved up or down the if statement triggers which checks if the movement is positive or negative. If the value is positive, 'Scroll up' is written to the console and it scrolls the user to the start of the page.

If it is negative, 'Scroll down' is written to the console and the div is stored in the variable element which is my destination to scroll down to. The constant y will store the position of the element + pixels currently scrolled, then `window.scroll()` will scroll to the top of the element.

By adjusting top: y-+ you can set the padding after the scroll in pixels.

```
 $(window).bind('mousewheel', function(event) {
     if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0) {
         console.log('Scroll up');
         window.scrollTo(0,0);
     }
     else {
         console.log('Scroll down');
         let element = document.querySelector('#PROJECTS-2');
         const y = element.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY;
         window.scroll({
             top: y,
             behavior: 'smooth'
         });            
     }
})
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you skip the jQuery and just use css scroll snap. (So long as you do not have to support IE11.)

Here is a simple example:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
  scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(100vh);
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}
section {
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  padding: 1rem;
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
h1  {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  font-size: calc(1rem + 3vw);
}
```

```html
<section style="background:red">
  <h1>One</h1>
</section>
<section style="background:blue">
    <h1>Two</h1>
</section>
<section style="background:green">
    <h1>Three</h1>
</section>
<section style="background:yellow">
    <h1>Four</h1>
</section>
```

Comment: my first try was scroll snap as i have made the body with svgs and groups from nav to footer so inserting sections will complicate things in alignment area and also scroll snap doesnt really work with svgs so id really appreciate if i can get a solution in js or jquery :)

Comment: lmao i finally figured out a way i shall answer my own question xD

Comment: glad you figured it out

Comment: haha ya thankyou and appreciate your effort to help man :)